# Please explain how this "joke" works, ダーウンロードってかぁ

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, katakana, slang

I have no idea how this joke is even supposed to be a joke.
In this video, 3 kids are laughing at the idea of uploading:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2qxzVteHto&t=0m12s

「だいたいアップロードってなんだよ？アップがあるんだったらダウンもあんのかよ」

「(laughing) ダ・ウ・ン　ロードってか(laughing)」

「あるんだよ！両方違法になる場合があるんだよ」

「アップロードも、ダウンロードも」

「あるのかよ」

Here is an answer I received on another site:
I think they're just putting emphasis on the word down, as opposed to up. (You can see the dude miming an object and placing something underneath)

Comment: You say "this video" but it's not linked. Did you mean to include a link?

Comment: To me it looks like they're just laughing because they're idiots, not that there's a joke.

Comment: The japanese are usually pretty witty and clever with their puns, and I do think there has to be some meaning to this. Like, maybe the first girl is asking, "Just what exactly is an 'upload' to begin with? If there is an 'up' part to something, there must be a 'down' part to it too!" Then the purple shirt kid might be saying something to the effect of, "Lol, a 'down'load!? Hahaha!" Since "up" and "down" are loanwords in japanese, they might think that that in itself is funny/humorous perhaps...

Comment: @Leebo:  I laugh because other people are idiots too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These students didn't know what アップロード and ダウンロード mean. They laughed simply because アップロード (and by extension, ダウンロード) sounded like a funny nonsense word to them.

In the days of classic [ヤンキー](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC_(%E4%B8%8D%E8%89%AF%E5%B0%91%E5%B9%B4)) like the ones depicted in the video, the internet was almost nonexistent. The setting of this video itself is something of a joke.